# Ada Array store unbounded String getting from .txt file

Tags: arrays, text-files, ada

Im having a trouble storing unbounded string to an array if I'mm getting it to .txt file. Here is my hardcoded data:

```
Data : An_Array := (1 => (Name => +"9 - Joe"),
                    2 => (Name => +"8 - Trisha "),
                    3 => (Name => +"7 - RR "),
                    4 => (Name => +"6 - Jane "),
                    5 => (Name => +"5 - Doe "));
```

What if I want to get the data from a `.txt` file?

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort;

procedure Main is

   function "+" (S : String) return Unbounded_String renames To_Unbounded_String;

   type A_Composite is
      record
         Name  : Unbounded_String;

      end record;

   function "<" (L, R : A_Composite) return Boolean is
   begin
      return L.Name < R.Name;
   end "<";

   procedure Put_Line (C : A_Composite) is
   begin
      Put_Line (To_String (C.Name));
   end Put_Line;

   type An_Array is array (Natural range <>) of A_Composite;

   procedure Sort is new Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort (Natural, A_Composite, An_Array);

   Data : An_Array := (1 => (Name => +"9 - Joe"),
                       2 => (Name => +"8 - Trisha "),
                       3 => (Name => +"7 - RR "),
                       4 => (Name => +"6 - Jane "),
                       5 => (Name => +"5 - Doe "));
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Open (File => File,
                     Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File,
                     Name => "highscore.txt");

   while not Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File (File) loop
         declare
            Line :String := Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line (File);            
         begin

              -- get data from .txt and I want it to sotre to Data : An_Array
            end;
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.Close (File);

   Sort (Data);
   for I in Data'Range loop
      Put_Line (Data (I));
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Comment: You'll find Get/Get_Line and Put/Put_Line for Unbounded_Strings in `Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO`, [RM A.10.12](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-12.html)

Comment: I want it to store in array. then after that i want it to sort that array.. THanks.

Comment: You can add a second attribute to `A_Composite` for score; you can read such values using an instance of `Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO`. Please edit your question to update your [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on any remaining problem you encounter.

Comment: ok if I add another attribute which is A_Composite. How will i store data within that array. Still confused.

Comment: I should have said add a second [*component_item*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-8.html) to the declaration of `A_Composite` in which to store the score for each record.

Comment: Can you please give me sample code? thanks.

Comment: [`scores_window_pkg`](http://linxtris.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/linxtris/linxtris/src/) is an example.

Comment: i already checked it but no luck for what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

In Ada, any particular array has a fixed length; your `Data` has a length of 5, even though your *type* `An_Array` can be used to declare arrays with any length you like (within reason! your computer only has a fixed amount of memory).

I’m guessing that you want to deal with files where you don’t know beforehand how many lines there are.

You could do this by declaring

```
Data : An_Array (1 .. 1000);
```

and keeping a count of how many entries you’ve used:

```
   Last : Integer := 0;  -- in case the file contains no lines!
begin
   while not Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File (File) loop
      Last := Last + 1;
      Data (Last) :=
        (Name => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String
           ((File)));
  end loop;
```

and when the loop ends `Data (1 .. Last)` contains your data (`Data (Last + 1 .. 1000)` contains empty strings).

But what if there are 1001 entries in your file?

You could try `Ada.Containers.Vectors` ([ARM A.18.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html)) and `Ada.Containers.Generic_Sort` ([ARM 18.29(9.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-26.html#p9.1)) - you’d have to work out how to specify `Before`, and to write your own `Swap` procedure.

Comment: I still have an error. expected type "A_Composite" define at line 180. found private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_Strings". If I apply your suggestion

Comment: Then you did something wrong on line 180.  If you want us to be more specific about what you did wrong, you'll need to be more specific about what line 180 looks like (and probably the surrounding lines).  :)

Comment: If you use `-gnatl` while compiling, you’ll get a nicely-formatted error report which will make it a lot easier for us to understand. But I’ve edited my answer to indicate what I think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an `Unbounded_String` in an array of `Unbounded_String`s is trivial:

```
An_Array (3) := An_Unbounded_String;
```

But is that your actual problem?

Comment: No. my problem is that I need to create an array.. while looping i need to insert data in array that data will come from .txt file.. after that I need to sort that array.