# An array of records containing variable-length strings

Tags: ada

I would like to have a record with an integer and a variable-length string in it, something like this:

```
type Entry is
record
    Value: Integer;
    Label: String;
end record;
```

I ran into [the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386314/ada-array-store-unbounded-string-getting-from-txt-file) that you can't put an unconstrained String in a record type, so following the advice at that link I tried

```
type Entry(Label_Length : Natural) is
record
    Value: Integer;
    Label: String(1..Label_Length);
end record;
```

But now the problem is, I want an array of these things:

```
Entries : Array(1..2) of Entry := (
    (Label_Length => 0, Value => 1, Label => ""),
    (Label_Length => 0, Value => 2, Label => "")
);
```

and I'm getting told

```
main.adb:17:28: unconstrained element type in array declaration
```

I just want to be able to declare a (constant) array of these things and type in the labels and values in an intuitive way (I already wasn't crazy about having to count string lengths and type in Label_Length by hand). How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have no idea of the maximum size of the label field you can use Ada.Strings.Unbounded.

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;    use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO; use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;      use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Ent is record
      Value : Integer;
      Label : Unbounded_String;
   end record;

   type ent_array is array (1 .. 4) of Ent;

   Foo : ent_array;
begin
   for I of Foo loop
      Put ("Enter a value: ");
      Get (I.Value);
      Skip_Line;
      Put ("Enter a label: ");
      I.Label := Get_Line;
      New_Line;
   end loop;

   Put_Line ("Array Foo contents:");
   for I of Foo loop
      Put (I.Value'Image & " ");
      Put_Line (I.Label);
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 7):

[`entry` is a reserved word.]

If you want an array, all the entries have to be the same size. The size of your second record is `Label_Length` (4) + `Value` (4) + `Label` (`Character` (1) * `Label_Length`) i.e. anything between 8 and just over 2**31 bytes.

The trick is to fix the maximum size *and give a default value*:

```
   subtype Ent_Label_Length is Natural range 0 .. 32;

   type Ent (Label_Length : Ent_Label_Length := Ent_Label_Length'Last) is
      record
         Value : Integer;
         Label : String (1 .. Label_Length);
      end record;
```

You can save yourself the trouble of writing this (and working out the length of each string) by using `Ada.Strings.Bounded` ([ARM A.4.4](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-4.html)).

Comment: If I were to use `Bounded`, how would I write codeblock 3 in my question? Just wrap each Label value with `To_Bounded_String`?

Comment: Yes, that would do it (and `To_String` to get the standard String back).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind slightly different syntax, you can also consider using the Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors package in place of arrays.  Then each element can be a different size.  And vectors can be used in for loops just like arrays can:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors; use Ada.Containers;

procedure Main is
    
    type Entry_Info(Label_Length : Natural) is
    record
        Value: Integer;
        Label: String(1..Label_Length);
    end record;
    
    package Vectors is new Indefinite_Vectors
        (Index_Type   => Positive,
         Element_Type => Entry_Info);
         
    use type Vectors.Vector;  -- so you can use the & operator
         
    Entries : Vectors.Vector := Vectors.Empty_Vector
        & (Label_Length => 0, Value => 1, Label => "")
        & (Label_Length => 1, Value => 2, Label => "A");
        
begin
    for Info of Entries loop
        Put_Line(Info.Value'Image & " => " & Info.Label);
    end loop;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another, but perhaps cruder, method is to put the strings on the heap and use access values:

```
type String_Ref is access String;
    
type Entry_T is record
  Value: Integer;
  Label: String_Ref;
end record;
```

To allocate the strings, use "new" with an initial value:

```
Entries : constant array(1..2) of Entry_T := (
  (Value => 1, Label => new String'("First entry")),
  (Value => 2, Label => new String'("Second entry"))
);
```

To get the value of a Label, deference with ".all":

```
for E of Entries loop
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (
        "Value" & E.Value'Image
      & ", label " & E.Label.all);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 3):

If we're posting odd solutions, you can also use a holder:

```
package String_Holders is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders
   (Element_Type => String);

type Entry_Is_Reserved is record
   Value : Integer;
   Label : String_Holders.Holder;
end record;
```

Comment: Could you please illustrate what to write for my third codeblock? The obvious (casting a string to `String_Holders.Holder`) doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because Ada doesn't have casting. The description of Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders in Annex A of the [ARM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-TOC.html) will show you the functions To_Holder and Element, and the procedure Replace_Element, which should do what you want.